# how can i add tabs, new line inside textarea content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to develop a blogging website where I am writing a code for creating a blog page, here I am taking the blog content using a textarea and after writing the blog content user has to publish using the publish button.

so I have to write a code for this textarea where I need to give tabs in paragraphs and next lines and scrollbar is there any way to achieve this? so that when I will be published this, there will be a proper paragraph in a blog?

```
<section class="body-section">
    <div class="blog-wrapper">
        <span class="title">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="title" placeholder="Title for your blog" id="txtTitle">
        </span>
        <span class="txtareaBody">
            <textarea name="txt" class="form-control" placeholder="start writing your blog.." id="comment" rows="20" scrollable></textarea>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="file" placeholder="upload thumbnail image" formnovalidate name="imgUpload" id="ImgUpload" class="form-control">
        </span>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: You may want to use a WYSIWYG editor for something like this, such as [Quill](https://quilljs.com/),  [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/tinymce/), [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/), etc

Answer (score 0):

To provide tab in paragraphs use the tab property and define the tab size.This would provide the required spacing in the text area.Here I have provided the code for your reference .
You can also refer the link provided to know more on inserting tabs and spaces in HTML:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-insert-spaces-tabs-in-text-using-html-css/

```html
<style>
.tab {
        tab-size: 2;
    }
    </style>
<section class="body-section">
    <div class="blog-wrapper">
        <span class="title">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="title" placeholder="Title for your blog" id="txtTitle">
        </span>
        <span class="tab">
            <textarea name="txt" class="form-control" placeholder="start writing your blog.." id="comment" rows="20" scrollable></textarea>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="file" placeholder="upload thumbnail image" formnovalidate name="imgUpload" id="ImgUpload" class="form-control">
        </span>
    </div>

</section>
```